# Excel Transpose with some constant data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose, vba

I have some data horizontally that I need to make vertical but also keep the first few pieces of information constant; here is an example:

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqZQ3.png)

I want it to look like this:

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jedD6.png)

The data that I am working with is more complicated than this and will be updated periodically. I was hoping to work with a floating range and the TRANSPOSE function but I can not seem to be able to get the repeating name information to work.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  This has been asked and answered many times both with formulas and vba.  If you have code that is not working then please post it in the original post and we will help overcome the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365839/excel-macrovba-to-transpose-multiple-columns-to-multiple-rows/36366394?noredirect=1#comment60428750_36366394

Comment: Thank you, I have been searching but haven't found this exact answer.

Comment: Depending on what version of Excel you have, you can use either Power Pivot, or in 2016, Data/Get and Transform/From Table.  Then, in the Query editor, just select all columns except the first two, and `Unpivot`

Comment: [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812).

Answer (score 0):

I always favour using the Multiple Consolidation Ranges feature of Pivot Tables, as it's so much less complicated for those who are unfamiliar with VBA.  Deconstructed many a file with this method.

Simple How-To guide here:
http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/transposing-a-dataset-with-a-pivottable/