# Vba code to partially transpose excel data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem to find a simple way to transpose these date from this form 
[image]

to this form so that I can create a pivot table, so I wish my result to look like this:

[image]

Does anyone has any idea about how can I transpose my multiline data partially, so that the category can become a column and the Vol and Item stay as columns?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What you are looking for is called `unpivot` and has been asked many times before: http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365839/excel-macrovba-to-transpose-multiple-columns-to-multiple-rows The only *difference* is that you have multiple columns to `unpivot` at a time. So, you'll most likely want to have a look at the second link. This answer is using VBA and can be easily adjusted for multiple columns. Yet, I am unsure where `Mickey` and `Client_Name` are coming from and why `modern` seems to be missing

Comment: Especially since your source data has merged cells, and is missing some information you want in your results, it won't be simple.  I suggest defining an object of type Category, where the properties are the different values (in a Class); gathering the appropriate information into a collection, and then organizing the output.  If you reorganized your source data, you could probably do an unpivot.