# Excel VBA, transforming Data leads to crashing of excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that crashes my excel, it takes the data from one sheet and transforms it from a tabular view to vertical. I believe it is slow because it is taking it from a database view to over 45k rows.

does anyone have any tips for optimizing this code? Crashes my excel at the `next c` loop

Also I tried running this in excel 2010, get an `overflow` error, but usually 2010 runs better and 2013 is slow or not responding. But I want to get it working for 2013.

```
Sub test()
    Call ReversePivotTable("Sheet1", "A", "C", "Sheet2", "Name")
End Sub



Sub ReversePivotTable(source_sheet, from_col, to_col, target_sheet, Optional type_header = "type", Optional value_header = "value")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LAST_ROW = Sheets(source_sheet).Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If LAST_ROW > 1 Then
        Sheets(target_sheet).Cells.ClearContents
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    pvt_type_col = Sheets(target_sheet).Range(to_col & 1).Offset(0, 1).column 'D
    pvt_value_col = Sheets(target_sheet).Range(to_col & 1).Offset(0, 2).column 'E

    'get headers
    Sheets(source_sheet).Range(from_col & ":" & to_col).copy
    Sheets(target_sheet).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(1, pvt_type_col).Value = type_header
    Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(1, pvt_value_col).Value = value_header



    'tranform data
    curr_row = 2
    With Sheets(source_sheet)
        last_col = .Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
            For Each c In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
                Set rng = .Range(.Cells(c.Row, pvt_type_col), .Cells(c.Row, last_col))
                numbers = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "<>""")
                If numbers > 0 Then
                    Sheets(source_sheet).Range(from_col & c.Row & ":" & to_col & c.Row).copy
                    Sheets(target_sheet).Range(from_col & curr_row & ":" & from_col & curr_row + numbers - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    b = curr_row
                    For a = pvt_type_col To last_col Step 1
                        If IsNumeric(.Cells(c.Row, a).Value) Then
                        'If .Cells(c.Row, a).Value <> "" Then
                            Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(b, pvt_type_col) = .Cells(1, a)
                            Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(b, pvt_value_col) = .Cells(c.Row, a)
                            b = b + 1
                        End If
                    Next a
                    curr_row = curr_row + numbers
                    If curr_row Mod 10 = 0 Then DoEvents
                End If
            Next c
    End With
    Sheets(target_sheet).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Adding sample data, before:

```
+---------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  col 1  |      col 2       |      col 3      |    col 4     |    col 5    |    col 6     |    col 7    |    col 8     |    col 9     |   col 10    |   col 11    |   col 12    |    col 13    |    col 14    |   col 15    |   col 16    | col 17 | col 18 | col 19 |    col 20    |    col 21    |   col 22    |    col 23    |   col 24    |   col 25    |   col 26    |   col 27    |    col 28    |   col 29    |    col 30    |   col 31    |    col 32    |   col 33    | col 34 | col 35 | col 36 | col 37 | col 38 | col 39 | col 40 | col 41 | col 42 | col 43 | col 44 | col 45 | col 46 | col 47 | col 48 | col 49 |
+---------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| stack   | questions forums | excel questions | -540.0689323 | 1543.570725 | -144.7954348 | 2298.261951 | -9019.970702 | -14669.27805 |  2400.31011 | 642.2459256 | 5573.176935 | -19167.60096 | -17070.78503 | 2884.343252 |   2262.2904 |      0 |      0 |      0 | -4866.524221 | -5470.616311 | 6722.889306 | -6749.153327 | 8483.707603 | 7513.052842 | 3768.659869 | 8600.703543 | -8642.799155 | 1322.251923 | -1323.911031 | 3651.739593 | -259.3401823 | 9369.890794 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
| stack   | questions forums | excel questions | -325.5117945 | 641.8568521 | -58.21010305 | 977.4626836 | -3505.695779 | -7455.410001 | 777.9341271 | 385.2714806 | 1932.531773 | -8861.136183 | -6679.463121 | 1177.775583 | 881.2548725 |      0 |      0 |      0 | -1813.822794 | -2266.860562 | 2278.669772 | -2361.758467 | 3356.446385 | 2741.992369 | 1461.950204 | 3289.154294 |  -3469.10217 | 804.7989704 | -816.9003551 | 1907.515323 |  432.8435868 | 3074.256129 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
| stack   | questions forums | excel questions | -36.42618332 | 65.26139258 | -6.513963305 | 99.38442773 | -435.0485137 | -1047.099199 | 79.09717611 | 39.17283622 | 186.7060257 | -1272.372107 |  -922.750792 | 118.3261869 | 89.60240903 |      0 |      0 |      0 | -210.3183182 | -267.1376584 | 214.6223869 | -280.0000537 | 293.4738136 | 248.5196226 | 144.0720039 | 288.5506437 | -430.0886416 | 81.82868405 | -91.41469707 | 184.4395708 |  44.00977438 | 272.8284368 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
| stack   | questions forums | excel questions | -582.3647427 | 1316.573479 | -165.4555206 | 1925.519573 | -7138.977944 | -17532.94829 | 1404.004642 | 930.6126154 | 3648.013625 | -19585.55834 |  -13758.8035 | 2376.319408 |   1898.9449 |      0 |      0 |      0 | -3625.886962 | -4833.808881 | 4232.764078 | -4449.956081 | 6883.584715 |  5398.12044 | 4048.773452 | 6632.405148 | -7240.871663 | 1959.676076 | -2008.657583 | 4413.431721 |  1360.661107 | 5484.849776 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
+---------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

desired after:

```
+---------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
|  col 1  |      col 2       |      col 3      | Attribute |    Value     |
+---------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 4     | -540.0689323 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 5     |  1543.570725 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 6     | -144.7954348 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 7     |  2298.261951 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 8     | -9019.970702 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 9     | -14669.27805 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 10    |   2400.31011 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 11    |  642.2459256 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 12    |  5573.176935 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 13    | -19167.60096 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 14    | -17070.78503 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 15    |  2884.343252 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 16    |    2262.2904 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 17    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 18    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 19    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 20    | -4866.524221 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 21    | -5470.616311 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 22    |  6722.889306 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 23    | -6749.153327 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 24    |  8483.707603 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 25    |  7513.052842 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 26    |  3768.659869 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 27    |  8600.703543 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 28    | -8642.799155 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 29    |  1322.251923 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 30    | -1323.911031 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 31    |  3651.739593 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 32    | -259.3401823 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 33    |  9369.890794 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 34    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 35    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 36    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 37    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 38    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 39    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 40    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 41    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 42    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 43    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 44    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 45    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 46    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 47    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 48    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 49    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 4     | -325.5117945 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 5     |  641.8568521 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 6     | -58.21010305 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 7     |  977.4626836 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 8     | -3505.695779 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 9     | -7455.410001 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 10    |  777.9341271 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 11    |  385.2714806 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 12    |  1932.531773 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 13    | -8861.136183 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 14    | -6679.463121 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 15    |  1177.775583 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 16    |  881.2548725 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 17    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 18    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 19    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 20    | -1813.822794 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 21    | -2266.860562 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 22    |  2278.669772 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 23    | -2361.758467 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 24    |  3356.446385 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 25    |  2741.992369 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 26    |  1461.950204 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 27    |  3289.154294 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 28    |  -3469.10217 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 29    |  804.7989704 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 30    | -816.9003551 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 31    |  1907.515323 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 32    |  432.8435868 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 33    |  3074.256129 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 34    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 35    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 36    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 37    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 38    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 39    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 40    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 41    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 42    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 43    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 44    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 45    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 46    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 47    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 48    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 49    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 4     | -36.42618332 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 5     |  65.26139258 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 6     | -6.513963305 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 7     |  99.38442773 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 8     | -435.0485137 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 9     | -1047.099199 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 10    |  79.09717611 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 11    |  39.17283622 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 12    |  186.7060257 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 13    | -1272.372107 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 14    |  -922.750792 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 15    |  118.3261869 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 16    |  89.60240903 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 17    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 18    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 19    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 20    | -210.3183182 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 21    | -267.1376584 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 22    |  214.6223869 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 23    | -280.0000537 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 24    |  293.4738136 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 25    |  248.5196226 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 26    |  144.0720039 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 27    |  288.5506437 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 28    | -430.0886416 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 29    |  81.82868405 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 30    | -91.41469707 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 31    |  184.4395708 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 32    |  44.00977438 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 33    |  272.8284368 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 34    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 35    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 36    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 37    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 38    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 39    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 40    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 41    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 42    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 43    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 44    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 45    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 46    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 47    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 48    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 49    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 4     | -582.3647427 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 5     |  1316.573479 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 6     | -165.4555206 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 7     |  1925.519573 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 8     | -7138.977944 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 9     | -17532.94829 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 10    |  1404.004642 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 11    |  930.6126154 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 12    |  3648.013625 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 13    | -19585.55834 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 14    |  -13758.8035 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 15    |  2376.319408 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 16    |    1898.9449 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 17    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 18    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 19    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 20    | -3625.886962 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 21    | -4833.808881 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 22    |  4232.764078 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 23    | -4449.956081 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 24    |  6883.584715 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 25    |   5398.12044 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 26    |  4048.773452 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 27    |  6632.405148 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 28    | -7240.871663 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 29    |  1959.676076 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 30    | -2008.657583 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 31    |  4413.431721 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 32    |  1360.661107 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 33    |  5484.849776 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 34    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 35    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 36    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 37    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 38    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 39    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 40    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 41    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 42    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 43    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 44    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 45    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 46    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 47    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 48    |            0 |
| stack | questions forums | excel questions | col 49    |            0 |
+---------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: try powerquery if you are simply doing an unpivot/pivot operation.

Comment: ^^ Is more effective with 64 bit but good with 32 as well.

Comment: @QHarr , thanks ill try it.. but do I have too!

Comment: Don't ***have*** to. But you could try it. It takes a few minutes tops. You put cursor in a populated cell then  data/powerquery tab > from table > then in pop-up window select the columns to unpivot > right-click > unpivot columns. Done. It's inbuilt in 2016. Free add-in for 2013.

Comment: Read about VBA arrays from Excel ranges. Or at least don't copy-paste, but transfer a value from cell to cell.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365839/excel-macrovba-to-transpose-multiple-columns-to-multiple-rows/36366394#36366394 for faster versions of your current code

Comment: @TimWilliams , could you help with the code? Its hard to alter it to what you have

Comment: Sorry- I don't have time to rewrite your code, but the link I posted should give you some ideas on how to avoid writing data cell-by-cell

Comment: @TimWilliams , thank you

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk , would you be able to help? hard to know how to replace stuff..

Comment: If you want to optimize this, you can ask for help on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps ask on StackOverflow how to approach a specific part of the code.

Comment: Did you find out what line causes error and crashes excel?

Comment: @MaciejLos , Yes `next c` loop causes it to crash. I suppose its the giant loop in the transform data section.

Comment: without knowing what the basic layout of what is on `sheet1` and `sheet2`, reading through and optimizing your code to your exact need will be hard to impossible to do

Comment: It will benefit you if you post a small, but relevant, sample of the source data and the expected output, so we can have a better idea of what you tried to achived with the code posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, but i don't want to analyse your code and even use it for set of reasons...

**First of all**, a common error within VBA programming is to used unspecified (undeclared) variables. This causes several issues, especially when a programmer have made a spelling mistake (typing error), for example instead of `myvariable` he used `myvairable`. So...
It's strongly recommended to use [Option Explicit statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement), because... as MSDN documentation states:

> If you do not specify a data type, the `Variant` data type is assigned
>   by default.
>
> (...)
>
> Variables of type `Variant` require more memory resources than most other variables
>
> (...)
>
> If a module includes the `Option Explicit` statement, a compile-time error will occur
>   when Visual Basic encounters a variable name that has not been previously declared,
>   or that has been spelled incorrectly.

For further details, please see:
[Wikipedia: Visual Basic for Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)
[VBA: Declaring Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-variables)
[Runtime vs Compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time)
[Office Talk: Working with VBA in the 32-bit and 64-bit Versions of Office 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/officetalk2010/ff700513(v%3Doffice.11))

**Second of all**, an [Overflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/overflow-error-6) error occurs when you try to make an assignment that exceeds the limitations of the target of the assignment. That error might be the reason of Excel crush.

**Third of all**, you should use code in context. Un-contextual usage of code might be the reason of several issues, such as loss of data.
Imagine: there are 2 opened workbooks. Both of them have the same set of sheets: `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`. When you use `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "whatever"` changes are made in active workbook, let's say `Workbook1`, but you wanted to make changes in `Workbook2`. Got it?
BTW: note, that `Sheet` is not the same as `Worksheet`
[Sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174306(v=office.11).aspx) vs. [Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508(v=office.11).aspx)
So, a proper way to use code-in-context is:

```
Dim srcWsh As Worksheet
Dim trgWsh As Worksheet

Set srcWsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'you can use index too, see:
Set trgWsh = Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets(2)

trgWsh.Range("A1") = srcWsh.Range("A1")

'finally, you have to clean up
Set srcWsh = Nothing
Set trgWsh = Nothing
```

The same rules have to be used when you create or call [procedure or function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/calling-sub-and-function-procedures)

**Finally...**
As to the method to reverse (unpivot) data...
I did use an example from MSDN: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017), where these data:

```
VendorID    Emp1    Emp2    Emp3    Emp4    Emp5
1           4       3       5       4       4
2           4       1       5       5       5
3           4       3       5       4       4
4           4       2       5       5       4
5           5       1       5       5       5
```

have to be "converted" into this form:

```
VendorID    Employee    Orders
----------- ----------- ------
1            Emp1       4
1            Emp2       3 
1            Emp3       5
1            Emp4       4
1            Emp5       4
2            Emp1       4
2            Emp2       1
2            Emp3       5
2            Emp4       5
2            Emp5       5
...
```

My code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    UnpivotData ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1"), _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz2"), _
        "A1", "B1:F1"
End Sub


Sub UnpivotData(ByVal srcWsh As Worksheet, ByVal trgWsh As Worksheet, ByVal unpvtFor As String, ByVal pivotedColumns As String, _
    Optional ByVal commonHeader As String = "Employee", Optional ByVal pvtValuesToCol As String = "Orders")

    'declare variables
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, trgr As Long
    Dim c As Long, cName As String

    'on error go to error handler
    On Error GoTo Err_UnpivotData

    'find last row
    lastrow = srcWsh.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'context!
    With trgWsh
        'clear
        .Cells.Clear
        'add headers
        .Range("A1") = srcWsh.Range(unpvtFor)
        .Range("B1") = commonHeader
        .Range("C1") = pvtValuesToCol
        '"convert" values
        r = 1
        trgr = 0
        'loop through the collection of rows in srcWsh
        Do While r < lastrow
            'loop through the collection of pivoted columns in srcWsh
            For c = 0 To srcWsh.Range(pivotedColumns).Columns.Count - 1
                'unpivot value of 1. column
                .Range("A2").Offset(RowOffset:=trgr, ColumnOffset:=0) = srcWsh.Range(unpvtFor).Offset(RowOffset:=r, ColumnOffset:=0)
                'unpivot header
                cName = srcWsh.Range(pivotedColumns).Columns(c + 1).Address
                .Range("A2").Offset(RowOffset:=trgr, ColumnOffset:=1) = srcWsh.Range(cName).Rows(1)
                'unpivot value
                .Range("A2").Offset(RowOffset:=trgr, ColumnOffset:=2) = srcWsh.Range(unpvtFor).Offset(RowOffset:=r, ColumnOffset:=c + 1)
                'increase target counter
                trgr = trgr + 1
            Next
            'increase source counter
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    End With

Exit_UnpivotData:
    On Error Resume Next
    'clean up

    Exit Sub

Err_UnpivotData:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_UnpivotData
End Sub
```

Feel free to change it to your needs...

Working example: [Unpivot.7z](https://www.myqnapcloud.com/smartshare/6d5e3l5kn2opo688486w8zcz_6yxdlqJ) - available to download between 7:01AM and 11:59PM Central Europe (Warsaw) Time

I hope i've explained in details what's wrong with your code.

**[EDIT]**
Assuming that data are in `Sheet1` and target sheet is `Sheet2`...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    UnpivotData ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2"), _
        "A1:C1", "D1:AW1"
End Sub


Sub UnpivotData(ByVal srcWsh As Worksheet, ByVal trgWsh As Worksheet, ByVal unpvtFor As String, ByVal pivotedColumns As String, _
    Optional ByVal commonHeader As String = "Attribute", Optional ByVal pvtValuesToCol As String = "Value")

    'declare variables
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, trgr As Long
    Dim c As Long, cName As String
    Dim cc As Range

    'on error go to error handler
    On Error GoTo Err_UnpivotData

    'change settings to improve speed of macro executing
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    

    'find last row
    lastrow = srcWsh.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'context!
    With trgWsh
        'clear
        .Cells.Clear
        'add headers
        For Each cc In srcWsh.Range(unpvtFor).Cells
            .Range("A1").Offset(ColumnOffset:=c) = Trim(cc)
            c = c + 1
        Next
        Set cc = .Range("A2").Offset(ColumnOffset:=c)
        .Range("A1").Offset(ColumnOffset:=c) = commonHeader
        c = c + 1
        .Range("A1").Offset(ColumnOffset:=c) = pvtValuesToCol
        '"convert" values
        r = 1
        trgr = 0
        'loop through the collection of rows in srcWsh
        Do While r < lastrow
            'loop through the collection of pivoted columns in srcWsh
            For c = 0 To srcWsh.Range(pivotedColumns).Columns.Count - 1
                'copy original data
                srcWsh.Range(unpvtFor).Offset(RowOffset:=r).Copy .Range("A2").Offset(RowOffset:=trgr)
                'unpivot data - attribute
                cName = srcWsh.Range(pivotedColumns).Columns(c + 1).Address
                cc.Offset(RowOffset:=trgr, ColumnOffset:=0) = Trim(srcWsh.Range(cName).Rows(1))
                'unpivot data - value
                cc.Offset(RowOffset:=trgr, ColumnOffset:=1) = Trim(srcWsh.Range(cName).Offset(RowOffset:=r))
                'increase target counter
                trgr = trgr + 1
            Next
            'increase source counter
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    End With

Exit_UnpivotData:
    On Error Resume Next
    'clean up
    Set cc = Nothing
    'restore previous settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

Err_UnpivotData:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_UnpivotData
End Sub
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks , can you explain where I put my sheets and some of my parameters into your code?

Comment: Have you tried to change my code to your needs? Where did you stuck?  I thought that my code (with comments) is quite understandable... But, if you need my help, i'm able to help you. Create new chat and invite me.

Comment: @excelguy, i've updated my answer respectively to your needs ;)

Comment: Thanks, ill test it out shortly. By the way what  is `Attribute`, `Value`, and `D1:AW1`? Having trouble figuring out which of my values go here

Comment: @excelguy, please download unpivot.xlsm. 'D1:AW1' is  an address of headers to reverse data into 'Attribute' and 'Value'.

Comment: I've had trouble downloading the sheet. Pc will not allow it.

Comment: @excelguy, OK. Here's a 7-zip archive: [Unpivot.7z](https://www.myqnapcloud.com/smartshare/6d5e3l5kn2opo688486w8zcz_6yxdlqJ)

Comment: Thanks , it seems to be working(no errors) but takes very long, still running its been 20 minutes now. Wondering if it will ever complete or just cause my excel to 'not respond'

Comment: Strange... Do you have another macros in your sheet which are called within events? If yes, you have to disable events and screen updating (right after `On Error...`. Do not forget to restore these settings in `Exit_UnpivotData` subroutine. BTW: Thank you for accepting my answer and you're very welcome.

Comment: I do have other macros that are called within events, do I have to disable them all or just in this sub? Could you show me in the answer?

Comment: Thanks for all your help, lol for some reason still taking long. but haven't got not responding yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Unpivot()
    Call ReversePivotTable("Sheet1", "A", "C", "Sheet2", "Name")
End Sub



Sub ReversePivotTable(source_sheet, from_col, to_col, target_sheet, Optional type_header = "type", Optional value_header = "value")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LAST_ROW = Sheets(source_sheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If LAST_ROW > 1 Then
        Sheets(target_sheet).Cells.ClearContents
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    pvt_type_col = Sheets(target_sheet).Range(to_col & 1).Offset(0, 1).Column 'D
    pvt_value_col = Sheets(target_sheet).Range(to_col & 1).Offset(0, 2).Column 'E

    'get headers
    Sheets(source_sheet).Range(from_col & ":" & to_col).Copy
    Sheets(target_sheet).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(1, pvt_type_col).Value = type_header
    Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(1, pvt_value_col).Value = value_header

    'tranform data
    curr_row = 2
    With Sheets(source_sheet)
        last_col = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            For Each c In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(c.Row, pvt_type_col), .Cells(c.Row, last_col))
                numbers = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, "<>""")
                If numbers > 0 Then
                    Sheets(target_sheet).Range(from_col & curr_row & ":" & from_col & curr_row + numbers - 1).Value = Sheets(source_sheet).Range(from_col & c.Row & ":" & to_col & c.Row).Value
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    b = curr_row
                    For a = pvt_type_col To last_col Step 1
                        If IsNumeric(.Cells(c.Row, a).Value) Then
                        'If .Cells(c.Row, a).Value <> "" Then
                            Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(b, pvt_type_col) = .Cells(1, a)
                            Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(b, pvt_value_col) = .Cells(c.Row, a)
                            b = b + 1
                        End If
                    Next a
                    curr_row = curr_row + numbers
                    If curr_row Mod 10 = 0 Then DoEvents
                End If
            Next c
    End With
    Sheets(target_sheet).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still getting excel not responding on the `Next c` part of the transform data part.

Comment: I actually created sample data and checked both your original code and my version I've presented. Yours took ages to complete - it's quite possible that slower machine could crash. However, corrected version - where I assign values to cell instead of copying them was quite fast (I have created 45k rows of sample data). If it's possible please show an example of actual data you are using this macro for.

Comment: Can I send you a sample sheet? Can you message me in chat?