# Get Position of Cell with a Value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

From this data:
[image]

I want to produce output like this:

[image]

Header is already made, but rest using a formula or vba.
Maybe get a position of cell where value > 0 and offset it or use xlUp/xlLef?
But then what if there are more data to left of fruits and above the dates?

Comment: What have you tried?  And where have you run into trouble?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365839/transpose-multiple-columns-to-multiple-rows-with-vba/36366394#36366394

Comment: You can try `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform`.  Select Column1 and then **UNpivot** other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this; manually select table and then run macro ... it will prompt for destination and write it out the list. Ignore's table cells that are blank.

```
Sub TableToList()

    Dim rngSelection As Range
    Dim rngDestination As Range
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngColumn As Long
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    ' Ensure that the selection is at least 2 rows and 2 columns
    Set rngSelection = Application.Selection
    If rngSelection.Rows.Count < 2 Or rngSelection.Columns.Count < 2 Then
        MsgBox "Selected data must have a minimum of two rows and two columns.", vbInformation
        End
    End If

    ' Ask the user to select the cell for where the list is to be written
    Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a destination cell:", Type:=8)

    ' Loop through the table and write out the list.
    lngCounter = 0
    For lngRow = 2 To rngSelection.Rows.Count
        For lngColumn = 2 To rngSelection.Columns.Count
            If ActiveCell.Cells(lngRow, lngColumn) <> "" Then
                rngDestination.Offset(lngCounter, 0) = ActiveCell.Cells(lngRow, 1)
                rngDestination.Offset(lngCounter, 1) = ActiveCell.Cells(1, lngColumn)
                rngDestination.Offset(lngCounter, 2) = ActiveCell.Cells(lngRow, lngColumn)
                lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```