# Transpose multiple rows of column of data into one column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to transpose multiple column of rows into one column

I understand this question has been asked, I have been trying to go by previous for a while but couldn't get it to work as needed. The problem I've had with previous examples is the output doesn't come in the format I need, it groups the numbers rather then doing it sequence.

Example array is:

```
1 1 1 
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

I know this size of data can be done in query editor in excel. But i need the sequence of data to be duplicated down 2300 lines. So my example array data would 2300 rows across which would take a lot of time to unpivot. Also the unpivot function doesn't merge the data into the order.

I've tried this example from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365839/transpose-multiple-columns-to-multiple-rows-with-vba) but could not it get to work as needed. Get a function or sub undefined.

```
Sub Tester()

Dim p

'get the unpivoted data as a 2-D array
p = UnPivotData(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
              3, False, False)
            
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1")
    .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
    .Resize(UBound(p, 1), UBound(p, 2)).Value = p 'populate array to sheet
End With

'EDIT: alternative (slower) method to populate the sheet
'      from the pivoted dataset.  Might need to use this
'      if you have a large amount of data
'Dim r As Long, c As Long
'For r = 1 To Ubound(p, 1)
'For c = 1 To Ubound(p, 2)
'    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, c).Value = p(r, c)
'Next c
'Next r

End Sub
```

I'm new to VBA and haven't explored it much, I am trying to find a example for this work.

### Edit

Could the example be flexible to allow column array of 500+ rows rather then matching the range of what's in the example only?

Comment: Does your table start in `A1`? Does it have headers? Do you want the data from e.g. `A2:C5` copy to `H2:H13`? It is understood that `C5` is `CLastRow`. Please confirm or clarify. An example with different data may be more appropriate.

Comment: no headers, the data i have is just 1-4 i want to transpole x rows of columns into one column. Starts cell A1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Stack Columns

[image]

- Download the workbook from [`Google Drive`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TXjW5tX2L8N-vPJi74OPzhqhWV7lLgwr/view?usp=sharing) (Down-arrow on the top-right).
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub stackColumns()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstColumn As String = "A"
    Const scCount As Long = 3
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirstCell As String = "H2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(sFirstColumn)
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount, scCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To srCount * scCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    
    For c = 1 To scCount
        For r = 1 To srCount
            n = n + 1
            Result(n, 1) = Data(r, c)
        Next r
    Next c
        
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirstCell)
        .Resize(n).Value = Result
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - n + 1).Offset(n).ClearContents
    End With
        
End Sub
```

### EDIT

```
Sub stackColumns2()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstColumn As String = "A"
    Const scCount As Long = 3
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirstCell As String = "H1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = wb.Worksheets(sName).Range("A1") _
        .CurrentRegion.Columns(sFirstColumn).Resize(, scCount)
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To srCount * scCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    
    For c = 1 To scCount
        For r = 1 To srCount
            n = n + 1
            Result(n, 1) = Data(r, c)
        Next r
    Next c
        
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirstCell)
        .Resize(n).Value = Result
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - n + 1).Offset(n).ClearContents
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for feedback, would column 2-6, be appended exactly below one column without it being in two seperate columns

Comment: works almost well but misses the first cell. Rather than the output being 1,2,3,4 x4. Its 2,3,4, x4.

Comment: I've added another version.

Comment: my apologies you've added a header, i just added a header to my table it works :). However, for my example ive extended the data range from 4 rows of columns to over 500 how do edit the code for it work. Tried playing with it to make it work but couldn't figure it out

Comment: You need only the number of columns: `scCount`. It is `3` in the sample data, you can use anything that is valid. In this case `<=16384`. `CurrentRegion` will determine the number of rows. They should be `<=1048756 / scCount`. If you want to do columns `2-6` then use `B` for `sFirstColumn` and `5` for `scCount`.

Comment: Perfect thank you for help, didnt realise i could change the scount to the range i need.

Answer (score 0):

To transform multiple columns into a single column, and maintain the column order instead of converting to row order, merely transpose the table before unpivoting.

eg:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(Source),
    #"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Transposed Table", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

On a matrix of 2500 columns * 100 rows, this query completed in less than one second.

[image]

Comment: whats the in, that in query editor tab in excel

Comment: I don't understand your question.  This is `Power Query M code`.  Accessed from `Data=>Get&Transform=>from Table/Range` in Windows Excel 2010+ or Excel Office 365. When you wrote **query**, I thought this was what you were referring to.