# Transform every all 5 rows to column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, row, transform

I need to help for you because i'd like to tranform data in my excel.

The example:

[image: 1 12 13 14 15]

I'd like to transfrom to in this form:

[image]

Do u have any tips for this?
I'm a "basic" excel user.

Please if i need use a VBA please give detailed description :D

Thank u in advance.

Comment: There was the exact same question very recently which I posted a solution to, you can try it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75280879/9852011

Comment: Welcome karesz55! The person who asked a question can mark one answer as "accepted". Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: A few steps in PowerQuery if that's a viable option too. See [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/power-query-stack-columns-vertically/372a32fe-4d17-4584-8226-c7366011e2aa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To Column By Column

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub ToColumn()
    
    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "A2:C6"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "E2"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range(SRC_RANGE)
    Dim Data(): Data = ToCol(srg, True)
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = ws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(UBound(Data, 1))
    drg.Value = Data

End Sub

Function ToCol( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ByColumns As Boolean = False) _
As Variant()
    
    Dim sData(), srCount As Long, scCount As Long
    Dim dData(), IsNotSingleCell As Boolean
    
    With rg.Areas(1)
        
        srCount = .Rows.Count
        scCount = .Columns.Count
        
        If srCount * scCount = 1 Then
            ReDim dData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): dData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            sData = .Value
            ReDim dData(1 To srCount * scCount, 1 To 1)
            IsNotSingleCell = True
        End If
    
    End With
    
    If IsNotSingleCell Then
        
        Dim sr As Long, sc As Long, dr As Long
        
        If ByColumns Then
            For sc = 1 To scCount
                For sr = 1 To srCount
                    dr = dr + 1
                    dData(dr, 1) = sData(sr, sc)
                Next sr
            Next sc
        Else
            For sr = 1 To srCount
                For sc = 1 To scCount
                    dr = dr + 1
                    dData(dr, 1) = sData(sr, sc)
                Next sc
            Next sr
        End If
    
    End If
        
    ToCol = dData
        
End Function
```

### (Legacy) Formula Solutions

By Columns

```
=INDEX($A$2:$C$6,
    MOD(ROWS($A$2:$A2)-1,ROWS($A$2:$A$6))+1,
    QUOTIENT(ROWS($A$2:$A2)-1,ROWS($A$2:$A$6))+1)
```

By Rows

```
=INDEX($A$2:$C$6,
    QUOTIENT(ROWS($A$2:$A2)-1,COLUMNS($A$2:$C$2))+1,
    MOD(ROWS($A$2:$A2)-1,COLUMNS($A$2:$C$2))+1)
```

[image]

**By Columns**

If the data starts in `A1`...

```
E1:E15  =MOD(ROW()-1,5)+1
F1:F15  =QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,5)+1
G1:G15  =INDEX($A$1:$C$5,MOD(ROW()-1,5)+1,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,5)+1)
```

... but it doesn't.

```
I2:I16   =MOD(ROW()-2,5)+1
J2:J16  =QUOTIENT(ROW()-2,5)+1
K2       =INDEX($A$2:$C$6,
             MOD(ROWS($A$2:$A2)-1,ROWS($A$2:$A$6))+1,
             QUOTIENT(ROWS($A$2:$A2)-1,ROWS($A$2:$A$6))+1)
```

**By Rows**

If the data starts in `A1`...

```
M1:M15  =QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)+1
N1:N15  =MOD(ROW()-1,3)+1
O1:O15  =INDEX($A$1:$C$5,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)+1,MOD(ROW()-1,3)+1)
```

... but it doesn't.

```
Q2:Q16  =QUOTIENT(ROW()-2,3)+1
R2:R16  =MOD(ROW()-2,3)+1
S2      =INDEX($A$2:$C$6,
            QUOTIENT(ROWS($A$2:$A2)-1,COLUMNS($A$2:$C$2))+1,
            MOD(ROWS($A$2:$A2)-1,COLUMNS($A$2:$C$2))+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TOCOL()` function.

```
=TOCOL(A1:C5,,TRUE)
```

#### Function reference:

[TOCOL()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/tocol-function-22839d9b-0b55-4fc1-b4e6-2761f8f122ed)

[image]

Comment: If you do not have `TOCOL()` then can try `=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,$A$1:$C$5)&"</s></t>","//s"),ROW(1:1))`

Comment: Unfortunately the TOCOL() function is not available in my office version.

Comment: @karesz55 What is you Excel version?

Comment: 2016 (16.0.5378.1000)

Comment: @karesz55 Can you try above one I give to comment?

Comment: of course , That was a first thing, then i saw that. And didn't workk. The result: "#NAME?

Comment: @Harun24hr Unfortunately, [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) needs at least Office 2019.

Comment: I tried on other PC with 2019 and it didn't work there either.. :\

Comment: @karesz55 You have to enter it as an array formula i.e. confirm with `Ctrl,Shift+Enter` in the first cell, and then copy down (start pasting from the 2nd cell).

Answer (score 0):

You can try following formula (normally entered) in `O365`:

`=INDEX($A$1:$C$5,0,CEILING(ROWS($A$1:A1)/5,1))`

For a setup depicted as below:

[image]

You may have to use *CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER* if you have different version of Excel.

Comment: I tried this formula, and didn't work for me. 1,12,13,14,15 row is okay But when 2, 22,23 would follow then te result is: "#value!"

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result still in the first column, something like the below image (before/after) :

[image] ==> [image]

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim i As Integer

With ActiveSheet 'change as needed
    Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("C2").End(xlDown)) 'change as needed
End With

For i = 1 To rg.Columns.Count - 1
    rg.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rg.Rows.Count, 1).Value = _
    rg.Columns(1).Offset(0, i).Value: rg.Columns(1).Offset(0, i).ClearContents
Next

End Sub
```

the rg is the range of data (in the example case is from cell A2 to C6).
it loops using i as the offset value, and each loop it fill the last blank row with the offset range value.