# how to separate text from an excel cell, and move it to the cell below

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table like this in Excel

CURRENT TABLE:

[image]

and I want to make it like this.
automatically

[image]

please can anyone help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose multiple columns to multiple rows with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365839/transpose-multiple-columns-to-multiple-rows-with-vba)

Comment: I'd look into powerquery. Looks like a few clicks will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Integer, ColCnt As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, arrRes(), arrNum
    ' Load data from activesheet, modify as needed
    arrData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    k = 0
    ' Loop through each row
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        ' Split by comma
        arrNum = Split(arrData(i, 2), ",")
        ' Populate the output
        For j = LBound(arrNum) To UBound(arrNum)
            k = k + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrRes(1 To ColCnt, 1 To k)
            arrRes(1, k) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(2, k) = "'" & arrNum(j)
            arrRes(3, k) = arrData(i, 3)
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Write output to new sheet
    Sheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A1").Resize(k, ColCnt).Value = Application.Transpose(arrRes)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**Update**

- `Transpose` can not handle long string ( more than 255 chars )
- It's difficult to determine the total number of rows for the output. Therefore, the code will write the output to the worksheet in batches.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Integer, ColCnt As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, arrRes(), arrNum
    Dim desSht As Worksheet, lastCell As Range
    Const BATCH = 10000 ' Moidfy as needed
    ' Load data from activesheet, modify as needed
    arrData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    k = 0
    Set desSht = Sheets.Add
    ' Loop through each row
    ReDim arrRes(1 To BATCH, 1 To ColCnt)
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        ' Split by comma
        arrNum = Split(arrData(i, 2), ",")
        ' Populate the output
        For j = LBound(arrNum) To UBound(arrNum)
            k = k + 1
            arrRes(k, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(k, 2) = "'" & arrNum(j)
            arrRes(k, 3) = arrData(i, 3)
            If k = BATCH Then
                Set lastCell = desSht.Cells(desSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
                If Len(lastCell) > 0 Then Set lastCell = lastCell.Offset(1, 0)
                lastCell.Resize(BATCH, ColCnt).Value = arrRes
                k = 0
                ReDim arrRes(1 To BATCH, 1 To ColCnt)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Write output to new sheet
    Set lastCell = desSht.Cells(desSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    If lastCell.Row > 1 Then Set lastCell = lastCell.Offset(1, 0)
    lastCell.Resize(BATCH, ColCnt).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

Comment: Masha Allah, very cool, just what I expected, thank you

Comment: sorry, I have a problem,
when the characters in a cell are more than 255 characters in column C,
then an error message appears.

Runtime Error '13'

Type Mismatch

Comment: Transpose can't handle large string. Please try the revised code.

Comment: you are truly amazing

after updating the code,
everything goes perfectly,
I can only say thank you.